# How to ignore or detect a symbol in a variable?

Tags: php, sql, query-string

I have a query that looks at a list of files inside a folder and enters the names of everything into a database so I can control the sort when showing the images.

Now I had an image today which had a name of `image123('2).jpg`. The single quote caused my query from crashing so how can I get around this? To make things simpler I have made example scenario

I have list of 4 variables which have the following strings

```
$myVAR1 -- "MyName IS Leo";

$myVAR2 -- "MyName IS 'Tiger";
```

I am running a SQL query to enter them into a database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `names` (`StringID`, `StringValue`) VALUES (NULL, ' $myVAR1');";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `names` (`StringID`, `StringValue`) VALUES (NULL, ' $myVAR2');";
```

So how can I detect that the single quote is inside the string `$myVar2` and how can I ignore it when entrying into the database?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your data.  Use [prepared queries with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) so you don't have to worry about this.

You are currently wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

At a minimum, use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), assuming you are using the standard MySQL library in PHP.  It takes care of quotes, among many other things, escaping them properly so they will be inserted into your database.